# map JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest, export-to-csv

I try to request data from a sites XHR and then save it as a CSV. The response is JSON and one part of the response is nested.
I have two issues:

- First: It doesn't iterate. It returns only data for the first object but in two rows. The same data on both rows except from the last column where the first row have floorPlan:AltText and the second row floorPlan:url
- Second: I doesn't like my some of my characters"'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2560' in position 147:...". Seems to be some UTF-8 problem

The format of the response is (it is shortened to be more readable here):

```
[{
"id":"67d3686f-848b-e911-a971",
"name":"1302",
"url":"/site/",
"residenceType":"3",
"objectStatus":"1",
"price":570000.0,
"fee":245.0,
"apartmentNumber":"1302",
"address":"Major street 8",
"rooms":4.0,
"floor":3.0,
"primaryArea":92.0,
"inhabitDate":"2022-02-28T23:00:00Z",
"floorPlan":{"url":"/externalfiles/image/1.jpg","altText":"Drawing"}},
{"id":"69d3686f-848b-e911-a971-000d3ab795ed",
"name":"1303",
"url":"/site2/",
"residenceType":"3",
"objectStatus":"1",
"price":320000.0,
"fee":113.0,
"apartmentNumber":"1303",
"address":"Major Street 8",
"rooms":2.0,
"floor":3.0,
"primaryArea":47.0,
"inhabitDate":"2022-02-28T23:00:00Z",
"floorPlan":{"url":"/externalfiles/image/2.jpg","altText":"Drawing"}},
```

And my code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json

h = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

u = "https://cdn-search-standard-prod.azureedge.net/api/v1/search/getstageobjects/23d8dbc1-005a-e911-a961-000d3aba65fd"

x = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w+"))

f.writerow(["id", "name", "residenceType", "objectStatus", "price", "fee", "apartmentNumber"])

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["id"],
                x["name"],
                x["residenceType"],
                x["objectStatus"],
                x["price"],
                x["fee"],
                x["apartmentNumber"],
                x["floorPlan"]["url"]])
    df=pd.DataFrame(x)
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Documents\Python Scripts\file_20200627.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert x to csv use pandas you are tring to convert x to csv but x is not a csv writer object and also you are writing rows at the same time

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json

h = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

u = "https://cdn-search-standard-prod.azureedge.net/api/v1/search/getstageobjects/23d8dbc1-005a-e911-a961-000d3aba65fd"

x = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w+"))

f.writerow(["id", "name", "residenceType", "objectStatus", "price", "fee", "apartmentNumber"])
print(x)
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["id"],
                x["name"],
                x["residenceType"],
                x["objectStatus"],
                x["price"],
                x["fee"],
                x["apartmentNumber"],
                x["floorPlan"]["url"]])
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Documents\file.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
```

output

```
id  name    url     residenceType   objectStatus    price   fee     secondaryArea   apartmentNumber     address     rooms   floor   maxFloor    concept     primaryArea     plotArea    inhabitDate     inhabitDateEnd  inhabitDateTimeStamp    inhabitDateDetermined   swanLabel   parkingSpaceStatus  floorPlan
altText     75d3686f-848b-e911-a971-000d3ab795ed    1504    /stockholm-lan/jarfalla-kommun/bolinder-strand...   3   1   3840000.0   1974.0  0.0     1504    Fabriksvägen 8  3.0     5.0     15.0    782ffe43-f9ef-40eb-8d92-cfd90aa6b147    73.0    0.0     2022-02-28T23:00:00Z    2022-04-30T22:00:00Z    1646089200000   False   True    1   Planritning
url     75d3686f-848b-e911-a971-000d3ab795ed    1504    /stockholm-lan/jarfalla-kommun/bolinder-strand...   3   1   3840000.0   1974.0  0.0     1504    Fabriksvägen 8  3.0     5.0     15.0    782ffe43-f9ef-40eb-8d92-cfd90aa6b147    73.0    0.0     2022-02-28T23:00:00Z    2022-04-30T22:00:00Z    1646089200000   False   True    1   /externalfiles/image/23d8dbc1-005a-e911-a961-0...
```

output csv file

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help but unfortunately it doesn't work. It doesn't like the syntax for dataframe df=pd.DataFrame(x)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @NewDev no i checked it is working because x is list .we can easy put list to create a data frame

Comment: sorry, don't understand what you mean. what shall I do in order to be able to write it to CSV?

Comment: Right! I had missed a ",". But now it say "'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2560' in position 147: character maps to <undefined>" which I assume is connected to that it doesn't like the swedish letter "å","ä","ö".

Comment: @NewDev Above code is i executed in my pc..and please share your code which is you are tryingto

Comment: `f.writerow(["id", "name", "residenceType", "objectStatus", "price", "fee", "apartmentNumber"])
print(x)
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["id"],
                x["name"],
                x["residenceType"],
                x["objectStatus"],
                x["price"],
                x["fee"],
                x["apartmentNumber"],
                x["floorPlan"]["url"]])
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Documents\Python Scripts\file_20200627.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
`

Comment: I can see in your picture that your export is " planlo╠êsning" but mine is "planloâ• Ãªsning" and the "╠" is \u2560

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216772/discussion-between-naga-raj-s-and-newdev).